# Cannot open Quarto documents - pandoc error (invalid character)

Tags: rstudio, pandoc, quarto

I have an R project with several .Qmd files, which I am no longer able to open. This happened seemingly over night. I am met with the below error every time I try to open a Quarto document:

`error pandoc.exe <stdout> commitbuffer invalid argument (invalid character)`

[image: Error message:]

In other of my projects, this error does not appear when I try to open the existing Quarto files, but it appears if I attempt to create a new Quarto document.

Markdown works fine.

The error does not appear when I open the files from the same projects on my work laptop.

I have tried:

- re-installing R (current and previous version)
- re-installing RStudio (current and previous version)
- re-installing Quarto
- re-installing Pandoc

Comment: You are much more likely to receive help if you can make this problem reproducible. I'd recommend making a copy, opening with with a plain text editor and then deleting text/chunks until you have distilled the document to the absolute minimum amount of content that reproduces the error. If you don't find a solution in that process, posting the reduced text of your notebook _(yaml header and all)_ will allow stack overflow users to better help you.